# Issues With Memory Usage in Windows Container

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure-web-app-service, containers

I am attempting to host a .NET 4.8 web application in a Windows container. The application uses COM interop to interact with some legacy components.

I started with a .NET 4.8 Web API project created through Visual Studio with Docker enabled. Everything works great on my machine. I am able to send hundreds of requests through JMeter/POSTMAN without error and the memory usage on my machine does not appear to exceed 1GB.

When I host the container in Azure App Service, it throws out of memory exceptions after 10-11 requests. This happens fairly consistently.

I've tried scaling up the App Service Plan. I found that by default, Windows containers in Azure App Service are limited to 1.5 GB of memory, so I used an app setting to increase this value to 10GB and I was able to confirm in the Deployment Center that the container IS created with 10GB of memory, but it still runs out of memory VERY quickly.

I eventually was able to reproduce this behavior on my own machine, and it turns out that no matter how high I set the memory limit (I've tried 20 GB)... ANY value specified with the '-m' parameter is causing the unacceptable performance.

In short:

`docker run -m 25GB -P <containername>:<tag>`

does NOT work, but:

`docker run -P <containername>:<tag>`

DOES work.

I'm guessing there must be more happening behind the scenes with this -m parameter than meets the eye.

The docker documentation has some other parameters related to memory usage, but when I pass those flags, I get the error that they are not supported for windows containers.

Any ideas? At this point I will probably have to abandon usage of Azure App Service and just host the containers in my own VM so that I can control the full run command and make sure that the -m parameter is NOT passed.

Comment: I don't think you can count on Azure App Service to support .Net web apps calling COM. It's just too "legacy" to be supported. This might actually be a good use case for a Docker swarm because if there is any instability (which I would expect for something that needs to do Web > .Net > .Net Interop > COM) the docker image can be killed and a stable one take it's place

Comment: @Nick.Mc I was hoping to utilize app service health checks for that, and I have them set up, it just happened too consistently to be reliable. Setting up the containers in AKS would be my next steps I guess. It seems like this would actually work fine if I could change the -m parameter that app service passes when starting the container. It seems like it works fine if it thinks it has infinite memory, even though it isn't actually using that much.

Comment: Just remember that the official term for this is "technical debt". Because you need to rely on COM, you need to implement all of these additional workarounds which in themselves add to system complexity and reduce reliability. If there is a $ decision maker involved in this, they need to be educated on technical debt.